# Functions on a hyperboloid

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

got a small problem here. 
[image]

This is what I want to have. The straight lines on the hyperboloid are defined as: γ(θ)±(t):=a(0,cosθ,sinθ)+at(1,∓sinθ,±cosθ), where a=1, t runs from -inf to inf and theta from 0 to 2pi.
Somehow I can't get it done. Also it would be nice to have a grid in the x-y plane and no vertical lines on the grid of the cone (except the functions of course ;)).

Thanks in advance.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,positioning,arrows,shapes}
    \begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        view={25}{25},
        axis lines = middle,
        height     = 12cm,
        width      = 12cm,
        xmin=-4,xmax=5,
        ymin=-4,ymax=5,
        zmin=-2,zmax=3,
        xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty, ztick=\empty,
        xlabel={$x^{2}$},
        ylabel={$x^{1}$},
        zlabel={$t$},
        ]   
        % x^2+y^2-z^2=1
        \addplot3[mesh,blue,domain=1:2,y domain=0:2*pi,samples=30]({x*cos(deg(y))},{x*sin(deg(y))},{sqrt(x^2-1)});    
        \addplot3[mesh,blue,domain=1:2,y domain=0:2*pi,samples=30]({x*cos(deg(y))},{x*sin(deg(y))},{-sqrt(x^2-1)});  
        \addplot3[red,thick,domain=-2:2,samples=30]({x},{cos(0)-x*sin(0)},{sin(0)+x*cos(0)});
        \addplot3[red,thick,domain=-2:2,samples=30]({x},{cos(0)+x*sin(0)},{sin(0)-x*cos(0)});
        \addplot3[red,thick,domain=-2:2,samples=30]({x},{cos(pi)-x*sin(pi)},{sin(pi)+x*cos(pi)});
        \addplot3[red,thick,domain=-2:2,samples=30]({x},{cos(pi)+x*sin(pi)},{sin(pi)-x*cos(pi)});
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Crossposting](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/18796/hyperboloid-mit-geraden-in-tikz?Seite=1#20309)

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\ViewAzimuth}{20}
\newcommand{\ViewElevation}{10}
\begin{axis}[
view={\ViewAzimuth}{\ViewElevation},
axis lines=none,
xmin=-2, xmax=2,
ymin=-2, ymax=2,
zmin=-2, zmax=2,
trig format plots=rad,
line join=round,
colormap/violet,
mesh/interior colormap={CM}{color=(lightgray) color=(white) color=(lightgray)},
]     
\addplot3[
surf, z buffer=sort,
domain=0:2*pi, samples=50, variable=v,
domain y=-1:1, samples y=50, variable y=z, 
]({cos(v)-z*sin(v)},{sin(v)+z*cos(v)},{z});
\foreach[parse=true] \a in {3/2*pi}{
\addplot3[red, thick, domain=-1:1, samples=2, variable=t, samples y=1]
({cos(\a)-t*sin(\a)},{sin(\a)+t*cos(\a)},t);
}
\draw[red, thick] (0,0,1) circle[radius=sqrt(2)];
\draw[red, thick] (0,{-sqrt(2)},-1) arc[radius=sqrt(2), start angle=-90, end angle=\ViewAzimuth];
\draw[red, thick] (0,{-sqrt(2)},-1) arc[radius=sqrt(2), start angle=-90, end angle=-180+\ViewAzimuth];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Hyperboloid with top/bottom circle and line]

Answer (score 2):

I think this is close enough to the picture shown (seen that in the OP code the option `mesh` is used) and it's very easy to draw directly with Ti*k*Z.

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[red,line cap=round,line join=round,3d view={110}{25}]
\def\h{2}
% grid
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=-\h]
  \fill[gray!5] (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
  \draw[gray]   (-3,-3) grid      (3,3);
\end{scope}
% circles
\foreach\i in {-1,-0.8,...,1}
  \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=\i*\h] (0,0) circle ({sqrt(1+\i*\i*\h*\h)});
% lines
\foreach\i in {0,15,...,359} \foreach\j in{-1,1}
  \draw ({cos(\i)+\j*\h*sin(\i)},{sin(\i)-\j*\h*cos(\i)},-\h) --
        ({cos(\i)-\j*\h*sin(\i)},{sin(\i)+\j*\h*cos(\i)}, \h);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here we have a circle (or an ellipse) as the base. The top is a shifted base. Let `A` is a realtive point with the relative time `t` on the base; move the relative time from `t` to `t+phase` to get a point `B` on the top; then draw a straight line `A--B`. That results an 1-sheet hyperboloid.

The lines `A--B` make a good-looking pattern themselves. The horizontal circles seems to be unnecessary. The code is implemented in the [Asymptote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU8V2.png) drawing language.

In case we want are interested in exact expression of both the hyperboloid and the straight lines on it, then simply use parameter equations of the hyperboloid with some maths calculations.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
//import three;
import grid3;

unitsize(2cm);
currentprojection=orthographic(2.5,1,.9,zoom=.9);
path3 Cbase=unitcircle3;
path3 Ctop=shift(0,0,1.5)*Cbase;
draw(Cbase^^Ctop,blue+1pt);

real phase=.35;
for (real t=0; t<1; t=t+.02) {
triple A=relpoint(Cbase,t);
triple B=relpoint(Ctop,t+phase);
draw(A--B,lightblue);  
}

// grid on XY-plane
real a=2;
limits((-a,-a,0),(a,a,0));
pen p=lightred+opacity(.5);
grid3(XYXgrid,Step=1,step=.5,p,p);
```